# How to get key and value from a dictionary after merging it from two list in Python?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have two list:

```
list_a = [<User: x>, <User: y>]
list_b = [False, True]
```

I want to create a dictionary by merging it. I did by the following code:

```
 details = dict(zip(list_a,list_b))
```

But i am not able solve the issue how to get the value in a template.

In my template code:

```
{% for x in details %}
   {{  }}
   {{  }}
{ % endfor %}
```

I have these two vacant tag in template. I want to put it as follow:

for the first iteration,

```
{{ x }}
{{ False}}
```

for second iteration,

```
 {{ y }}
 {{ True}}
```

..and so on

Comment: can you please post better example for list_a .... post sample data please instead of pseudocode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% for key, value in details.iteritems %}
    {{ key }}
    {{ value }}
{ % endfor %}
```